# Inventory Aging Report (FIFO)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

Have a problem to solve in the SQL Server to generate a Inventory aging report using FIFO Based on SKU & Warehouse. I have attached the schema here.

| SKU | TransactionType | WarehouseCode | TransactionDate | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | IN | WH1 | 2021-04-30 | 100 |
| 100 | IN | WH2 | 2021-04-30 | 50 |
| 101 | IN | WH1 | 2021-04-30 | 30 |
| 101 | IN | WH2 | 2021-05-01 | 25 |
| 100 | OUT | WH2 | 2021-05-02 | 30 |
| 100 | OUT | WH1 | 2021-05-02 | 20 |
| 100 | OUT | WH1 | 2021-05-04 | 50 |
| 100 | OUT | WH2 | 2021-05-04 | 20 |
| 100 | OUT | WH1 | 2021-05-05 | 25 |
| 100 | IN | WH2 | 2021-05-10 | 30 |
| 100 | IN | WH1 | 2021-05-11 | 30 |
| 101 | OUT | WH2 | 2021-05-12 | 20 |
| 100 | OUT | WH1 | 2021-05-15 | 30 |

Based on the above schema structure, i need to develop a inventory aging report based on first in first out (FIFO) and show the remaining qty of each SKU and Warehouse combination and make the previous incoming records remaining quantities as zero.

Expected report format Assuming the report is run on (2021-05-20)

| SKU | TransactionType | WarehouseCode | TransactionDate | Qty | Remaining | Aging |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | IN | WH1 | 2021-04-30 | 100 | 0 | 21 |
| 100 | IN | WH2 | 2021-04-30 | 50 | 0 | 21 |
| 101 | IN | WH1 | 2021-04-30 | 30 | 30 | 21 |
| 101 | IN | WH2 | 2021-05-01 | 25 | 5 | 20 |
| 100 | IN | WH2 | 2021-05-10 | 30 | 30 | 11 |
| 100 | IN | WH1 | 2021-05-11 | 50 | 5 | 10 |

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because No demonstrated effort to solve the problem.

Comment: @nicomp apologies for the not putting the options that i have tried. This is my first question in stack overflow, i will improve my question writing going forward. Appreciate your valuable feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions to sum up the `IN` records over time *(a cumulative sum)*, and find out the final total `OUT`.

Then, if the `in_so_far` is less than the `final_out`, you know you have use everything for that line.

The `aging` just appears to be a `datediff()` against a constant value?

```
WITH
  cumulative AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    SUM(CASE WHEN TransactionType = 'IN' THEN Qty ELSE 0 END)
      OVER (
        PARTITION BY SKU, WarehouseCode
            ORDER BY TransactionDate
      )
        AS qty_in_so_far,
    SUM(CASE WHEN TransactionType = 'OUT' THEN Qty ELSE 0 END)
      OVER (
        PARTITION BY SKU, WarehouseCode
      )
        AS qty_out_final
  FROM
    inventory
)
SELECT
  *,
  CASE
    WHEN qty_out_final > qty_in_so_far
      THEN 0
    WHEN qty_in_so_far - qty_out_final > qty
      THEN qty
      ELSE qty_in_so_far - qty_out_final
  END
    AS qty_final,
  DATEDIFF(day, TransactionDate, '2021-05-20') + 1             AS aging
FROM
  cumulative
WHERE
  TransactionType = 'IN'
ORDER BY
  TransactionDate,
  SKU,
  WarehouseCode
```

Demo... https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b6725edd625001cd874bdb8f37283763

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for, Thank you so much @MatBailie. You have saved my day.

Comment: if stock goes negative then there is a wobble :-)

try these values

(999, 'IN', 'XXX', '2021-05-15', 50),
(999, 'OUT', 'XXX', '2021-05-15', 20),
(999, 'OUT', 'XXX', '2021-05-16', 40),
(999, 'IN', 'XXX', '2021-05-16', 50),
(999, 'OUT', 'XXX', '2021-05-17', 5),
(999, 'OUT', 'XXX', '2021-05-18', 10),
(999, 'OUT', 'XXX', '2021-05-19', 26);

Comment: @GrahamH - Negative stock levels are physically impossible.  If the OP needs to cope with demand exceeding supply, the question needs to be refined.  *(Besides, this query just showing how much of an `IN` is remaining after all the `OUT`s have been applied.  The answer of `0` is correct in the case of demand exceeding supply.)*

Comment: @MatBailie.  in the real world there are many reasons why a computed stock level may be negative.............will wait and see what the OP has to say.

Comment: @GrahamH Like MatBailie mentioned this is inventories in warehouse usecase and no possibility of order placing when there is no on hand quantity.